# "Facebook Page: Not found example.com", the domain was verified six months ago in the "Business Settings"

Tags: domains, facebook

For many years, when I share a link to any of the pages of my website on Facebook, I find an "i" icon that leads to the following message:

- example.com registered: More than 10 years ago From WHOIS
- Facebook Page: Not found example.com
- When available, we show information about a website so people can learn more about it. If you recognize example.com, you can help identify their official Facebook Page.

The last message includes a button captioned "Review Page suggestions". If I click it, the first proposed Facebook page is mine (6k likes, categorized in "News & media website"). I've selected it dozens of time to suggest Facebook to use it.

The domain was created in 2005 and I verified it through Facebook's "Business Settings" ("Brand Safety") six months ago. I expected this issue to be fixed by the end of the year, but the problem continues.

I was wondering if there is anything else I need to do in addition to verifying the domain.

If it's useful, in the "Domains" section of "Business Settings" the 'example.com' domain is verified under my "Business Account" called "Business of 'My name'".